# Potential Heap Pollution via varargs for Function in Java Stream api

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, variadic-functions

I created the following method to convert a string containing a comma separated list to a set, eventually applying one or more function.

Is it safe to add the `@SafeVarargs` annotation in my case?

The `map` function of `Stream` expects `<? super String, ? extends String>` in its signature, so i'm supposing i'm not performing any unsafe operation. Am i right?

Can you give also examples of unsafe ops in this specific case?

```
@SafeVarargs
public static Set<String> commaSeparatedToSet(String str, Function<String, String>... functions) {
    if (str != null) {
        Stream<String> stream = Stream.of(str.split(",", -1))
                .filter(item -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(item))
                .map((elem) -> elem.trim());
        if (functions != null) {
            for (Function<String, String> function : functions) {
                stream.map(function);
            }
        }
        return stream
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    } else {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just realized that is enough for me to define a new interface and avoid the generic usage:

`public static interface StringFunction extends Function<String, String> { }`

Comment: I just realized that is enough for me to define a new interface and avoid the generic usage:

`public static interface StringFunction extends Function<String, String> { }`